# How to change my dataframe into nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
col1   col2   col3
1       4      6
5       2      3
6       1      0
```

I want to turn it into nested list:

```
array([[1,5,6],[4,2,1],[6,3,0]])
```

How could i do that?

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't `df.T.values` work?

---

```
array([[1, 5, 6],
       [4, 2, 1],
       [6, 3, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

or `df.T.values.tolist()`

---

```
[[1, 5, 6], [4, 2, 1], [6, 3, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df=  pd.DataFrame([[1,4,6],[5,2,3],[6,1,0]])

df.T.values
### returns >> array([[1,5,6],[4,2,1],[6,3,0]])
```